# When I run an Android project in Delphi, I get an error message

Tags: android, delphi, exec

When I run an Android project in Delphi, I get this error message.

> Error
>
> Cannot open file "C:\Users\pc\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\EXEC". The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> OK

Comment: Please provide more information and also read through this page -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think he gets the error in the message console after compilation, but before execution of the program. I have seen a similar message once when I tried to add additional android libraries to my program and I did not find a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

The file system under Android is not the same as it is under Windows. Your file path for the missing file is only appropriate under Windows.
I use the following code to access a file in the user's documents area which works under both file systems (not tested on iOS).

```
TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'yourfilename.txt');
```

You will require System.IOUtils in your uses clause to use this.